# Blender 3.0 for Windows - face normals not being displayed

Tags: modeling, mesh, normals

In my Blender 3.0 on Windows, the face normals are not showing when I enable them from Viewport Overlays, regardless of what size I set. Also, I checked the color for face normals in Preferences -> Themes -> 3D Viewport and it's a bright Cyan that should be visible.
Vertex and edge normals are showing just fine.
This is independent of what file I'm opening.

Am I missing something or did I just run into a Blender bug?

[image: Face normals not showing]

Comment: Yeah, that's strange, they should be there. I can see them in my copy of 3.0 on Win10. Maybe try factory reset, or re-install?

Comment: They're all showing here under W10 although the edge ones are almost invisible against my dark background.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett yeah, I'll eventually try those, although I hate having to re-install all my plugins and redo all the settings.